# lowercase `s` as prefix in `describe-bindings`

Tags: key-bindings, osx, modifier-key

[MacOS, running 28.2 from emacsformacos.com]

When I do `describe-bindings` I see that the "Global Bindings" includes a bunch of bindings with the prefix `s` - **not** `S` for "Shift".

[image]

What is the `s` prefix?

Comment: I think it means "super" key. Usually the "Win" key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s-` is the key-description for the <kbd>Super</kbd> modifier key, written as pseudo function key `<Super>`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Modifier Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).

And the Emacs manual node [Glossary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html) says this:

> **Super**
>
> Super is the name of a modifier bit that a keyboard input character may have. To make a character Super, type it while holding down the `SUPER` key. Such characters are given names that start with `Super-` (usually written `s-` for short). See [Modifier Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).

For macOS see also Emacs manual node [Mac / GNUstep Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Basics.html).